# Regular expression replace with callback

Tags: regex, haskell

I would like to perform string search and replace with regular expressions but have been unable to find a function that does what I need. I'm looking for something similar to my mythical `regexReplace` whose potential signatures I give below:

```
regexReplace :: Regex -> (String -> String) -> String -> String
```

or

```
regexReplace :: Regex -> (RegexMatch -> String) -> String -> String
```

This is roughly equivalent to `preg_replace_callback` in PHP. It takes a compiled regular expression represented by `Regex`, a replacement function (whose parameter would either be `String` or some match type `RegexMatch`), a source string and returns the result.

What would be the closest match to this behaviour among the many Haskell regular expression libraries that are out there?

Update:

I may need the callback to run inside `IO`, so I may end up needing the following function signature:

```
regexReplace :: Monad m => Regex -> (RegexMatch -> m String) -> String -> m String
```

This is obviously turning into a far more general problem than the original problem statement. I may end up using Parsec or similar.

Basically, I have the following program and haven't been able to figure out how to fill in the blank:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}

module Main where

import Data.Maybe
import System.Environment

data Regex = Regex {
  regexPattern :: String
}
data RegexMatch = RegexMatch {
  regexGroups :: [String]
}

regexReplace :: Monad m => Regex -> (RegexMatch -> m String) -> String -> m String
regexReplace Regex{..} f source =
  -- What do I put here?
  undefined

replacementValue :: [String] -> IO String
replacementValue groups =
  case groups of
    whole : name : defaultValue : [] -> do
      lookupResult <- lookupEnv name
      let value = fromMaybe defaultValue lookupResult
      return value
    otherwise -> error "Unexpected groups"

main :: IO ()
main = do
  replaceResult <- regexReplace
    (Regex "ENV:([A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_0-9]*):([A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_0-9]*)")
    (\RegexMatch{..} -> replacementValue regexGroups)
    "some input containing ENV:foo:bar replacement expressions"
  putStrLn replaceResult
```

Conclusion:

Using `regex-applicative` as suggested by @DanielWagner, I came up with the solution below which is quite elegant:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}

module Main (main) where

import Data.Char
import Data.Functor.Compose
import Data.Maybe
import System.Environment
import Text.Regex.Applicative

data EnvMatch = EnvMatch {
    envMatchName :: String
  , envMatchDefault :: String
}

-- Matches pattern "_env:SOME_NAME:SOME_DEFAULT_VALUE"
envPattern :: RE Char EnvMatch
envPattern = EnvMatch
    <$ string "_env:"
    <*> token
    <* string ":"
    <*> token
    where
        token :: RE Char String
        token = many (psym $ \c -> isAlphaNum c || c == '_')

expandEnv :: EnvMatch -> IO String
expandEnv EnvMatch{..} = fmap (fromMaybe envMatchDefault) (lookupEnv envMatchName)

queryTransform :: RE Char (IO String)
queryTransform = getCompose . (concat <$>) . sequenceA . map Compose $
    [
        pure <$> many anySym
      , expandEnv <$> envPattern
      , pure <$> many anySym
    ]

runQueryTransform :: String -> IO (Maybe String)
runQueryTransform = sequenceA . match queryTransform

main :: IO ()
main = do
  result <- runQueryTransform "hello\"_env:HOME:default_home_dir\"world"
  print result
  -- Yields: Just "hello\"/home/user\"world"
```

Thanks, @DanielWagner!

Comment: Solutions should be posted in the answer field rather than [edits to the post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319747/editing-potential-answers-into-questions).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may like [regex-applicative](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-applicative), which offers:

```
match :: RE Char String -> String -> Maybe String
```

You can replace specific parts of the match in the code that builds the value of type `RE Char String`. For example, here is a function which finds a string of `a` and `b` characters and reverses them:

```
import Text.Regex.Applicative
asAndBs   = many (psym (   `elem` "ab"))
noAsAndBs = many (psym (`notElem` "ab"))
transformation = concat <$> sequenceA [noAsAndBs, reverse <$> asAndBs, noAsAndBs]
```

Some example runs in ghci:

```
> match transformation "ntoheuuaaababbboenuth"
Just "ntoheuubbbabaaaoenuth"
> match transformation "aoesnuthaosneut"
Nothing
```

To handle your updated question: here is a transformation which looks for a string of `a` and `b` characters and asks the user what to replace them with. It reuses `asAndBs` and `noAsAndBs` from before, only modifying the transformation applied to them. I also include an example driver of `queryTransform` just to show how it might be used. The basic idea is to build up, rather than a flat replacement string, an `IO` action which produces the replacement string. It is then the job of the consumer who calls `match` to execute that `IO` action as appropriate.

```
import Data.Functor.Compose
queryTransform = getCompose . (concat <$>) . sequenceA . map Compose $
    [ pure <$> noAsAndBs
    , getLine <$ asAndBs
    , pure <$> noAsAndBs
    ]
runQueryTransform = getLine >>= sequenceA . match queryTransform
```

I hope you recognize the parallels between the `queryTransform` structure and the `transformation` structure from before (in particular note that the `(concat <$>) . sequenceA` construct is just like before). Here's some examples in ghci:

```
> runQueryTransform
oeunthaaabbbaboenuth
replacement
Just "oeunthreplacementoenuth"
> runQueryTransform
aoeunthaoeunth
Nothing
```

Comment: I don't see any replacement or substitution functions in this library.

Comment: @RichardCook, those aren't needed! The `Applicative` instance gives you all the power you need.

Comment: @RichardCook `match` *is* the replacement and substitution function.

Comment: @RichardCook I have amended my answer to discuss the use of `IO` during replacement.

Comment: @DanielWagner: I've updated the original question with an implementation based on regex-applicative. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have [Text.Regex](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-compat-0.95.1), which contains `subRegex`. I'm not sure what a callback is in PHP, but I don't think you can translate that into Haskell directly.

Comment: A callback allows you to make the replacement text a function of what was matched.

Comment: The `(String -> String)` part of the function signature is the callback. This is a function that takes the match and returns the replacement. Another viable callback function might be `(RegexMatch -> String)` where `RegexMatch` is the type representing the matched string.

Comment: `subRegex` is very close to what I want. Instead of a constant `String` as the replacement value, I want to be able to compute the replacement value as a function of the matched value. I'll also need it to access some outside state (hence the "Update" to my original question).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform search and replace in Haskell, then consider
pattern matching with
[`megaparsec`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec)
parsers instead of regular expressions. With that
you can use
[`streamEdit`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/replace-megaparsec/docs/Replace-Megaparsec.html#v:streamEdit),
which has exactly the signature of your mythical `regexReplace` function, or
[`streamEditT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/replace-megaparsec/docs/Replace-Megaparsec.html#v:streamEditT), which allows the callback to be run inside `IO`.

Here is a parser variant of your elegant `regex-applicative` solution which doesn't
require the `queryTransform` or `runQueryTransform` functions.

```hs
:set -XRecordWildCards
:set -XTypeFamilies
import Replace.Megaparsec
import Text.Megaparsec
import Text.Megaparsec.Char
import System.Environment
import Data.Char
import Data.Maybe

data EnvMatch = EnvMatch
    { envMatchName    :: String
    , envMatchDefault :: String
    }

-- Matches pattern "_env:SOME_NAME:SOME_DEFAULT_VALUE"
envPattern = EnvMatch
    <$ string "_env:"
    <*> tokes
    <* string ":"
    <*> tokes
  where
    tokes = many $ satisfy (\c -> isAlphaNum c || c == '_')

expandEnv :: EnvMatch -> IO String
expandEnv EnvMatch{..} = fmap (fromMaybe envMatchDefault) (lookupEnv envMatchName)

streamEditT envPattern expandEnv "hello\"_env:HOME:default_home_dir\"world"
```

```hs
"hello\"/home/user\"world"
```